# Exploding complex nested XML in spark

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, databricks

Hello everyone ,

I am trying to parse an xml file in spark. I am using explode function to flatten the data. Below is the input,output schemas and code.

```
 Input Schema
   root
     |-- _no: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _sc double (nullable = true)
     |-- _xsi: string (nullable = true)
     |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- con: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- co: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- cr: date (nullable = true)
     |    |-- pe: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- st: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- scs: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- _te: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- scle: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- cId: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- eId: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- ent: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- eent: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- MSId: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- _date: date (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- uas: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- tes: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- tv: uct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- LUE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _dour: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- nete: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- netSy: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- parum: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- UE: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Parts: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sa: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- VA: boolean (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- stitled: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- LUE: boolean (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tvering: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- dfLUE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _body: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ubting: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _LUE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- dy: string (nullable = true)
```

Output Required.

```
root
 |-- _no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _sc double (nullable = true)
 |-- _xsi: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- con: string (nullable = true)
 |-- co: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cr: date (nullable = true)
 |-- pe: string (nullable = true)
 |-- st: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- scs: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- _te: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scle: array (nullable = true)
 |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |-- cId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- eId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ent: array (nullable = true)
 |-- eent: struct (containsNull = true)
 |-- MSId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- uas: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tes: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tv: uct (nullable = true)
 |-- LUE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _dour: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nete: string (nullable = true)
 |-- netSy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parum: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- UE: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Parts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sa: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- VA: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ng: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stitled: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- LUE: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ng: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tvering: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- dfLUE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ubting: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- _LUE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dy: string (nullable = true)
```

The xml file is of 100MB in size and when I read the xml file, the count of the data frame is showing as 1. I believe spark is reading whole xml file into a single row.

Code used to explode,

```scala
val readxml = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","on")\
   .option("inferschema","true").load("/path")
val co= readxml.withColumn("cId", explode(col("scs.scle.cId")))
  .withColumn("eId", explode(col("scs.scle.schedule.eId")))
  .withColumn("exploded_sc", explode(col("scs.scle.ent")))
  .withColumn("uas", explode(col("exploded_sc.uas")))
  .withColumn("ag_dt", explode(col("exploded_sc._date")))
  .withColumn("time", explode(col("exploded_sc.tes.time")))
  .withColumn("MSId", explode(col("exploded_sc.MSId")))
  .withColumn("exploded_tv", explode(col("exploded_sc.tv")))
val finalDF = co.select(col("_sc"),col("header.*"),col("scs._te").as("_te"),
       col("cId"),col("eId"),                          
       col("MSId"),col("time"), col("exploded_tv._dour").as("_dour"),
       col("exploded_tv.tvering.dfLUE").as("tvra"),
       col("exploded_tv.tvering._body").as("body"),
       col("exploded_tv.parum.UE").as("pnum"),
       col("exploded_tv.parum.Parts").as("npart"),
       col("exploded_tv.ubting._LUE").as("tsting"),
       col("exploded_tv.ubting.dy").as("tsting_body"),
       col("exploded_tv.nete").as("netsrce"),
       col("exploded_tv.netSy").as("nettype"),
       col("exploded_tv.sa.VA").as("sp"),
       col("exploded_tv.sa.ng").as("lg"),
       col("exploded_tv.stitled.dfLUE").as("subled"),
       col("exploded_tv.stitled.ng").as("sud_ng"),
       col("uas"),col("ag_dt"))
```

I am getting output schema as required from the above code. But I am unable to view the data of finalDF .I suspected it is because of huge data. Then I started to take the count of each explode after reading the xml file. Then I got to know that the explode function is exponentially increasing the row count because of duplicates. Is there any alternate way to achieve the above output. Could someone please assist. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to explode? Directly refer the column way you are doing it inside explode!

Comment: @mohd avais. Do you mean directly select the nested  coloum name in the select query. Could you please elaborate with an example using the schema above.

Comment: readxml.select(col("scs.scle.cId").as("cId"), 
                         col("scs.scle.schedule.eId").as("eId"),
                         col("scs.scle.ent").as("exploded_sc"),
                         ....)

explode will flatten the arrays to different rows thereby increasing the count

Comment: I tried the above, but the output is the array of elements.For instance the output of cId is like [100638, 100640, 100641, 100699...] I actually need each cId in each row. In the same way I need  the value of each of the column mentioned above in separate row instead of array of elements

Comment: In the 3rd select column value col("scs.scle.ent").as("exploded_sc") , the data type of ent is array. so when I select exploded_sc.MSId, Im getting the below error. org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field MSId in cId, eId, ent;

Comment: Array elements on a different row means you need to explode but then the rows will multiply. You need to then consider your Spark job memory configurations. Regarding the second point, array elements can be accessed with index and not name as in structs. You can do it like exploded_sc(0).MSId

Comment: I tried the above and to show few rows of data itself it is taking lots of time. could  you please let me know if there is any way to achieve this output

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using arrays_zip function. Thank you

Comment: @SanjanaSanju Can you please past you code example to as reference? I'm facing the same issue.